# Select <options> loaded by jquery not getting serialized

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I have loaded a form. In the form there is a select area that when changed calls a ajax query to load and display a second level select area

```
$('.subjectareaid').change (function ()
     {
      var selected = $(this);
      var ssindex = selected.closest("tr").index()+1;
      var putid = '#subsub'+ssindex;
      var pdata = 'subjectareaid='+selected.val();
      $.ajax({
         type   : "POST",
         cache  : false,
         url    : "a_subsubject.php",
         data   : pdata,
         success: function(data) {
          $(putid).html(data);
          $(putid).removeClass('hideme');
         }
      });
     });
```

the a_subsubject.php file creates a list of options to be returned

```
 <option value=".$row['subsubjectid']."> ".$row['subsubjectname']
```

The HTML that is modified is a table, and in the table are the rows. The row looks like:

```
$outline .= "<tr><td>".$oline."Question ".$k."</td><td valign=bottom><select name=dif[".$j."]>".$difsel."</select></td><td valign=bottom><select class=subjectareaid name=sub[".$j."]>".$subsel."</select></td><td valign=bottom><select class=hideme id=subsub".$j." value=subsub[".$j."]><option value=0></select></td></tr>";
```

where $oline is either blank or a section name, $k is the question number, $j is the index (1-54), $difsel is a select statement's options, $subsel is a select statements options and the third selection is set to a single option, and hidden with the hideme class. In addition it has a ID that allows it to have the HTML refilled with the options being returned by the a_subsubject.php ajax call.

All of this table is wrapped in a form

```
 <form id=deform1>
```

When the form is submitted the following jquery is run:

```
     var formser =  $('#deform1').serialize();
     var crud = "&crud=scd";
     var scorecardid = '&scorecardid='+ escape($('input[name=id]').val());
     var pdata = formser+'&action=cru'+crud+scorecardid;
```

This is then sent to an ajax routine with pdata being the data being passed to the CRUD program to update the database.

The result (as displayed from an alert) from making selection in all three select values for questions 1, 21 and 39, are: {the id=1 is a hidden field ignored by the receiving code as it is captured and sent as the scorecardid later in the post string}

id=1&dif%5B1%5D=0&sub%5B1%5D=2&dif%5B2%5D=0&sub%5B2%5D=0&dif%5B3%5D=0&sub%5B3%5D=0&dif%5B4%5D=0&sub%5B4%5D=0&dif%5B5%5D=0&sub%5B5%5D=0&dif%5B6%5D=0&sub%5B6%5D=0&dif%5B7%5D=0&sub%5B7%5D=0&dif%5B8%5D=0&sub%5B8%5D=0&dif%5B9%5D=0&sub%5B9%5D=0&dif%5B10%5D=0&sub%5B10%5D=0&dif%5B11%5D=0&sub%5B11%5D=0&dif%5B12%5D=0&sub%5B12%5D=0&dif%5B13%5D=0&sub%5B13%5D=0&dif%5B14%5D=0&sub%5B14%5D=0&dif%5B15%5D=0&sub%5B15%5D=0&dif%5B16%5D=0&sub%5B16%5D=0&dif%5B17%5D=0&sub%5B17%5D=0&dif%5B18%5D=0&sub%5B18%5D=0&dif%5B19%5D=0&sub%5B19%5D=0&dif%5B20%5D=0&sub%5B20%5D=0&dif%5B21%5D=3&sub%5B21%5D=4&dif%5B22%5D=0&sub%5B22%5D=0&dif%5B23%5D=0&sub%5B23%5D=0&dif%5B24%5D=0&sub%5B24%5D=0&dif%5B25%5D=0&sub%5B25%5D=0&dif%5B26%5D=0&sub%5B26%5D=0&dif%5B27%5D=0&sub%5B27%5D=0&dif%5B28%5D=0&sub%5B28%5D=0&dif%5B29%5D=0&sub%5B29%5D=0&dif%5B30%5D=0&sub%5B30%5D=0&dif%5B31%5D=0&sub%5B31%5D=0&dif%5B32%5D=0&sub%5B32%5D=0&dif%5B33%5D=0&sub%5B33%5D=0&dif%5B34%5D=0&sub%5B34%5D=0&dif%5B35%5D=0&sub%5B35%5D=0&dif%5B36%5D=0&sub%5B36%5D=0&dif%5B37%5D=0&sub%5B37%5D=0&dif%5B38%5D=0&sub%5B38%5D=0&dif%5B39%5D=2&sub%5B39%5D=3&dif%5B40%5D=0&sub%5B40%5D=0&dif%5B41%5D=0&sub%5B41%5D=0&dif%5B42%5D=0&sub%5B42%5D=0&dif%5B43%5D=0&sub%5B43%5D=0&dif%5B44%5D=0&sub%5B44%5D=0&dif%5B45%5D=0&sub%5B45%5D=0&dif%5B46%5D=0&sub%5B46%5D=0&dif%5B47%5D=0&sub%5B47%5D=0&dif%5B48%5D=0&sub%5B48%5D=0&dif%5B49%5D=0&sub%5B49%5D=0&dif%5B50%5D=0&sub%5B50%5D=0&dif%5B51%5D=0&sub%5B51%5D=0&dif%5B52%5D=0&sub%5B52%5D=0&dif%5B53%5D=0&sub%5B53%5D=0&dif%5B54%5D=0&sub%5B54%5D=0&action=cru&crud=scd&scorecardid=1

as you can see dif%5B1%5D=0&sub%5B1%5D=2&dif%5B2%5D=0&sub%5B2%5D=0 this shows that sub[1] has been set to 2. This caused subsub1 to get loaded with a set of select options and then shown. A select option was made (the second item) yet no subsub[1] is being captured by the serialize of the form data. [this was also done with record 21 and record 39].

Am I missing some way of "updating" the form prior to making the serialize to capture the third jquery added select  values?

Comment: Come on folks, someone must have seen this type of issue before. Is the DOM not being updated correctly? Is there something that I need to do to make sure that the DOM is updated and that the form serializes properly?

Answer (score 0):

okay, the code is 300 lines in one file and 400 lines in another...

```
 $outline .= "<tr><td>".$oline."Question ".$k."</td><td valign=bottom><select name=dif[".$j."]>".$difsel."</select></td><td valign=bottom><select class=subjectareaid name=sub[".$j."]>".$subsel."</select></td><td valign=bottom><select class=hideme id=subsub".$j." value=subsub[".$j."]><option value=0></select></td></tr>";
```

looks fine, but this one line of code has ONE error in it.

```
<td valign=bottom><select class=hideme id=subsub".$j." value=subsub[".$j."]><option value=0></select>
```

select statements don't have "value", they have "name".

25 hours of time wasted chasing down one bad line of HTML. Okay, I feel foolish. Hard to believe I wrote a bloody book on CGI programming for Prentice Hall back in 1997. I am so glad I use a anon handle and not my own name right now. :-)